# Node.js replication screws up message ordering

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq

I have a replicated Node.js REST service (4 processes) that does nothing else than pushing tasks in a queue. It is extremely important that those tasks are being processed in order. Hence, they should be ordered in the queue.

RabbitMQ preserves the order in which message put a queue. However, with 4 concurrent processes I can't guarantee that the messages are put into the queue in the right order.

How to address this problem?

Comment: How is the order defined?